# Magento 2 : Cart summary is coming jumbled on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1.3, knockoutjs

Cart summary is coming jumbled on cart page in Magento 2.1.3 . I am not getting any js errors in console, please check screenshot .

[image: jumbled cart]

Please help me, if someone else faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by disabling `modpagespeed` in .htaccess of magento root.
It can be done by adding following code in .htaccess ;

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```